# Ajax add to cart issue in Woocommerce 2.5.2

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Woocommerce and I've customized my site to display the product titles in a table and when clicked the product is placed via ajax in the Woocommerce mini-cart widget without a page refresh.

When I update to 'Woocommerce 2.5.2' the Ajax add to cart no longer works and the page refreshes.

The current link I use to add a product is:

```
$html = $html . '<div class="numlist_thumb"><a data-product_id="' . $id1 . '" data-product_sku="' . $number1 . '" class="numbertabanchor add_to_cart_button dp-button product_type_simple" rel="nofollow" href="/?add-to-cart=' . $id1 . '">' . $number1 . '</a></div>';
```

I would really appreciate any suggestions as to how to add a product via ajax without a page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

This is the theme conflicts with woocommerce. I faced this problem too. So whenever the woocommerce launched any major update, theme also updated according to latest woocommerce. So you have to update your theme according to woocommerce.

Comment: Thanks but themes and plugins are up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Add the "ajax_add_to_cart" class to your `<a>` tag

As a reference have a look at my code for single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php

```
<button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button add_to_cart_button button ajax_add_to_cart button--itzel button--text-thick" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="<?php echo $product->id; ?>"><i class="button__icon icon icon-cart"></i><span><?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create the add to cart functionality via the `[wp_ajax][1]` action, and in the callback function you can simply add the following code

```
add_action( "wp_ajax_custom_add_to_cart", "custom_add_to_cart_callback" );
add_action( "wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_add_to_cart", "custom_add_to_cart_callback" );
function custom_add_to_cart_callback(){
     global $woocommerce;
     $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $_POST[ 'prod_id' ] );
     wp_die();
}
```

After this you can easily just make an ajax call to the server, where you will post the product id as variable `prod_id` and add another variable named action with value `custom_add_to_cart`